# When i trying to install SVN Connectors i got below error. I used eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

[image]

I have installed SVN in eclipse. Then after i gave repository URl,Username and Password. In that time i got below error.

> SVN: '0x00400006: Validate Repository Location' operation finished
>   with error: Selected SVN connector library is not available or cannot
>   be loaded. If you selected native JavaHL connector, please check if
>   binaries are available or install and select pure Java Subversion
>   connector from the plug-in connectors update site. If connectors
>   already installed then you can change the selected one at:
>   Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector. Selected SVN connector
>   library is not available or cannot be loaded. If you selected native
>   JavaHL connector, please check if binaries are available or install
>   and select pure Java Subversion connector from the plug-in connectors
>   update site. If connectors already installed then you can change the
>   selected one at: Window->Preferences->Team->SVN->SVN Connector.

==> I went That location i try to install the SVN Connectors. In that time i got below error.

Please solve my problem as soon as possible.

Comment: are you able to open the repo location in browser using the url

Answer (score 0):

That means you didn't installed any connectors. so, to install the connectors, follow the steps below.

In Eclipse, goto help--> Install New Software

in,install window, enter the below url in work with text field http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/update-site/

then in the below box you'll get list of connectors, select those and click next...

EDIT:

The link is an update site for Eclipse 2.0 which is quite old. For Eclipse Luna, this page gives the instructions. Copy this link for the update site if you know the procedure.

Comment: I used your given link i got error. like                                                                                           Artifact not found: http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/update-site/content.jar.
Artifact not found: http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/update-site/content.jar.
http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/2.0/update-site/content.jar